# Oracle 12c- upgrade

Tags: oracle

“The non-CDB architecture is deprecated in Oracle Database 12c, and may be de-supported and unavailable in a release after Oracle Database 12c Release 2. Oracle recommends use of the CDB architecture.” what unavailabe means here ? Does the oracle will not allow NON CDB architecture post Release 2 ?

Comment: "may" != "will" but otherwise that is my understanding. Under Oracle 12.1 you can create a stand-alone database (not using the multi-tenant architecture). What Oracle is saying there is that this option **may** not be offered in versions beyond 12.2.

Answer (score 2):

> The non-CDB architecture is deprecated in Oracle Database 12c, and may be desupported and unavailable in a release after Oracle Database 12c Release 2. Oracle recommends use of the CDB architecture.

**Deprecated:** Meaning Oracle doesn't enhance the feature any more but will be available throughout the release.

**Desupported:** Meaning Oracle doesn't fix the bugs related to the release.

**Unavailable:** Meaning the feature may not be included the future release.

**Conclusion:** Better not to use deprecated features.

Reference: [Non-CDB architecture of Oracle databases is DEPRECATED since Oracle Database 12.1.0.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/UPGRADE/entry/non_cdb_architecture_of_oracle)